# Neo4j fulltext index setup

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am following this tutorial by Michael http://jexp.de/blog/2014/03/full-text-indexing-fts-in-neo4j-2-0/ to setup my full text index. But there are couple of issues I ran into.

I have a node server running on my PC (windows). Anyway, I have something running on localhost that uses jQuery. So I used jQuery to make an ajax post call in the chrome console.

**Step1:**

```
 $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/node/',
    type: 'post',
    data: JSON.stringify({'name': 'NewIndex', 'config':{'type':'fulltext', 'provider':'lucene', 'to_lower_case': 'true'}}),
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": 'application/json',
        "Accept": 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

This worked! So it created an index. Next as the tutorial suggests, I setup these settings and restarted the server:

**Step 2:**

```
node_auto_indexing=true
node_keys_indexable=description
```

Next I used the following to reset properties

**Step 3:**

```
MATCH (n:anodelabel)
WHERE has(n.description)
SET n.description=n.description
```

Next I tried to query it in the browser localhost:7474.

**Step 4:**

```
START anodelabel=node:NewIndex("description:word*")
MATCH (o:anodelabel)<-[r:AUTHOR]-(user)
RETURN o LIMIT 10
```

But this is returning an empty set. So I tried to post a new item `CREATE (n:anodelabel {description: "needs to work"})` and used the cypher call again. Again an empty set.

Answer (score 0):

In step 4, the index return value is a node, not a node label. Try this instead:

```
START n=node:NewIndex("description:word*")
MATCH (n)<-[r:AUTHOR]-(user)
RETURN n LIMIT 10
```

Comment: It gives me this error: `Cannot match on a pattern containing only already bound identifiers (line 2, column 1)
"MATCH (n)"`

Comment: What version of neo4j are you running? I am using 2.1.5, and this query works for me. Also, are you using the same exact query?

Comment: My bad I just did `START n=node:NewIndex("description:word*")
MATCH (n)
RETURN n LIMIT 10` and it was giving me the error (no idea why)... however even after using the exact query you've suggested, I am still getting an empty set :(

Comment: The error was because the `MATCH` clause had no additional work to do. You could have eliminated `MATCH (n)`, and it should have worked. Do you actually have nodes with a `description` property value that contains the "word" string? Furthermore, do any of those nodes have an incoming `:AUTHOR` relationship?

Comment: Yes, pretty sure. Just to confirm it I created another node with just one word: `CREATE (n:anodelabel {"description":"testword"})<-[:AUTHOR]...` ... I can get this by MATCH (n:anodelabel)<-[:AUTHOR]-(a) WHERE n.description = "testword" RETURN n... But if i use `START n=node:NewIndex("description:testword*") MATCH (n)<-[r:AUTHOR]-(user) RETURN n LIMIT 10` ... this still gives an empty set.

Comment: As a sanity check, does this page (`http://localhost:7474/webadmin/#/index/`) list `NewIndex` as a lucene index? Also, does this page (`http://localhost:7474/webadmin/#/info/`) show `node_auto_indexing` is true and `node_keys_indexable` is "description" (without the quotes)?

Comment: Yes all of these in order => shows the index as lucene index with value `{"to_lower_case":"true", "type":"fulltext"}` ... auto indexing is true and keys shows `description` ... :(

Answer (score 0):

In your first step you should have used `node_auto_index` instead.

And in your last step too.

Only then your nodes get automatically added to that index.

Also your statement is not correct, use something like this:

1. find text nodes from FTS
2. assure their label and match patterns
3. return data

.

```
START o=node:NewIndex("description:word*")
MATCH (o:AnodeLabel)<-[r:AUTHOR]-(user)
RETURN user LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score -3):

```
MATCH (n:anodelabel)
WHERE has(n.description)
SET n.description=n.description
```